# slowest integrable sequence of function

Tags: real-analysis, functions, convergence-divergence, real-numbers

Let $I$ (integrable) be the set of continuous functions $f:\mathbb R_+\to\mathbb R_+$ that are integrable and nonincreasing.  Let $D$ (divergent) be the set of continuous functions $g:\mathbb R_+\to\mathbb R_+$ with $\lim_{x\to\infty}g(x)=\infty$.

**Claim.**  For any $f\in I$ there exists $g\in D$ such that $fg\in I$.

**Proof.**  This is well-known, and the equivalent question for series appeared many times on this site:  take
$$
g(x) = \left[\int_x^\infty f(t)dt\right]^{-1/2}.
$$
**My question.**  Can we find a sequence $(f_n)$ of functions in $I$ for which there does not exist $g\in D$ such that $f_ng\in I$ for all $n$?

This question is closely related to [the nonexistence of a boundary between divergent and convergent series](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/49415/nonexistence-of-boundary-between-convergent-and-divergent-series).  The sequence $f_n$ would somehow "converge" to that boundary, which does not exist, and intuitively this suggests that $(f_n)$ cannot exist.

A prototypical attempt of $f_n$ is as follows.  Let $\log^{(1)}(x)=\max(1,\log x)$ and $\log^{(n)}(x)$ the $n$-fold composition of $\log^{(1)}$ (well-defined and $\ge1$ for all $x\ge0$).  Set
$$
f_n(x)=\frac1{x\log^{(1)}(x)\dots\log^{(n)}(x)}
\frac1{\log^{(n)}(x)}.
$$
Of course $f_n$ are very close to nonintegrable functions, which suggests that there is no corresponding $g$.  However there is such a $g$:  Let $a_n=\exp(\exp(\dots (\exp(n)))$ (exponentiation $n$ times) and define $g(a_n)=n$, and extend by linear interpolation.  Clearly $g$ is monotone and divergent.  Moreover $g(x)\le \log^{(n)}(x)$ for all $x\ge a_{n+1}$, which shows that $f_ng$ is integrable for all $n$.

I would happily accept an answer to the analogous question for series, as I believe that there shouldn't be a difference when dealing with functions instead of series.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, an answer for series can easily be converted to an answer for(continuous) functions.

Notation for a sequence of sequences is awkward, so let's talk about functions $f_n,g:\Bbb N\to(0,\infty)$ instead.

> > If $\sum_jf_n(j)<\infty$ for $n=1,2,\dots$ then there exists $g$ such that $g(j)\to\infty$ but $\sum_jf_n(j)g(j)<\infty$ for every $n$.

Proof: Choose $N_1<N_2<\dots$ so that $$\sum_{j=N_k}^\infty f_n(j)<1/k^3,\quad(n=1,2,\dots, k).$$

Define $g$ by $$g(j)=k,\quad(N_j\le j<N_{k+1}).$$

Then for every $n$, if $k>n$ we have $$\sum_{j=N_k}^{N_{k+1}-1}
f_n(j)g(j)\le1/k^2.$$

Comment: Neat solution!  Here is a sort of translation of this to the functional version.  Let $g_n\to\infty$ such that $f_ng_n$ is integrable.  We may assume that $g_n> g_{n+1}$ for all $n$.  Pick numbers $a_n$ such that $g_n(a_n)=n$, define $g(a_n)=n$ for all $n$ and extend by linear interpolation.  Then for $a_{k+1}\ge x\ge a_k$ with $k\ge n$ we get $g(x)\le g(a_{k+1})=g_k(a_k)+1<g_n(a_k)+1\le g_n(x)+1$.  This shows that $gf_n$ is integrable for all $n$;  clearly $g\to\infty$ (because $a_n< a_{n+1}$).